# Excel VBA loop through 2 columns and only copy cells of one range that meets criteria

Tags: vba, excel, foreach, conditional-formatting

**My issue:**

I want to loop through a range, and whenever it finds a coloured cell, it should copy the cell to the left to the cell to the right of it. And then afterwards paste it into an other worksheet.

My sheet called “Compare” compares two sets of data, whereas a FormatConditions is applied as xlUniqueValues... The two sets of data, should contain the same data, but sometimes, there will be some, which are not within the other range. It is these cells that I am interested in finding with my loop, and then doing the processes if the criteria is met.

My code doesn't loop through the cells and returns me this message:

> Run-time error '1004": Method 'CountIfs' of object 'WorksheetFunction' failed

A screenshot of some of the data in Sheet "Compare":

[image: Screenshot of Sheet "Compare"]

**My Code:**

```
    Sub LoopForCondFormatCells()

    Dim sht3, sht4 As Worksheet
    Dim ColB, ColG, ColBG c As Range
    Set sht3 = Sheets("Compare")
    Set sht4 = Sheets("Print ready")
    Set ColG = sht3.Range("B3:B88")
    Set ColB = sht3.Range("G3:G86")


    HosKvik = sht4.Columns("B").Find("Hos Kvik, men ikke bogføring", Lookat:=xlWhole).Address(False, False, xlA1)
    HosKvikOff = sht4.Range(HosKvik).Offset(1, 0).Address(False, False, xlA1)
    Set HosKvikOffIns = sht4.Range(HosKvikOff).Offset(1, -1)    
    ColBG1 = ColB & "," ColG
    Set ColBG = Range(ColBG1)
'In the following For Each strings, I would like it to look in the range ColBG, _
but it should only return the value it finds in ColB... _
But I don't know how to write the code to do so
For Each c In ColB.Cells
    If Not IsEmpty(c) Then
        n = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ColBG, c) 'Error here
        If n = 1 Then
            c.Offset(0, -1).Resize(1, 3).Copy
            HosKvikOffIns.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            Set HosKvikOffIns = HosKvikOffIns.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

**Goal:**

I want the macro to loop through the cells, and find whatever cells, which has the FormatConditions type "xlUniqueValues". Whenever it comes across a cell, which is FormatConditions type "xlUniqueValues", it should do the steps:

```
For Each c In ColB.Cells
    If Not IsEmpty(c) Then
        n = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(ColBG, c) 'Error here
        If n = 1 Then
            c.Offset(0, -1).Resize(1, 3).Copy
            HosKvikOffIns.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
            Set HosKvikOffIns = HosKvikOffIns.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    End If
Next
```

What should I write in my "If c Is" line to get the macro to do what I want it to do? Is it even possible for me to loop two different ranges, and only return whatever xlUniqueValue that is in range G?

Comment: What is `ColBG1 = ColB & "," ColG`? You are passing a `non-consecutive` range in the `Countif` function, that won't work. Instead try it like `n = Application.CountIf(ColB, c) + Application.CountIf(ColG, c)`

Comment: The thing is that those two ranges are compared to each other, whereas, if they’re taken apart, the will point out only unique values... So I need it to loop, or atleast identify the cell, and copy it to sht4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Countif's  range is incorrect.

```
Sub LoopForCondFormatCells()

    Dim sht3 As Worksheet, sht4 As Worksheet
    Dim ColB As Range, ColG As Range, ColBG As Range, c As Range
    Dim Wf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim vR() As Variant
    Dim k As Long, j As Integer

    Set Wf = WorksheetFunction

    Set sht3 = Sheets("Compare")
    Set sht4 = Sheets("Print ready")

    Set ColG = sht3.Range("B3:B88")
    Set ColB = sht3.Range("G3:G86")
    'ColBG1 = ColB & "," ColG
    'Set ColBG = Union(ColG, ColB)
'In the following For Each strings, I would like it to look in the range ColBG, _
but it should only return the value it finds in ColB... _
But I don't know how to write the code to do so
For Each c In ColB.Cells
    If Not IsEmpty(c) Then
        With Wf
            n = .CountIfs(ColG, c) 'Error here
            If n = 0 Then
                k = k + 1
                ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 3, 1 To k)
                For j = 1 To 3
                    vR(j, k) = c.Offset(0, j - 2)
                Next j
            End If
        End With
    End If
Next
sht4.Range("a1").Resize(k, 3) = Wf.Transpose(vR) '<~~The unique values  are written below cell a1 in Sheet 4.
End Sub
```

The above is faster using arrays, and below is how to copy the range.

```
Sub LoopForCondFormatCells()

    Dim sht3 As Worksheet, sht4 As Worksheet
    Dim ColB As Range, ColG As Range, ColBG As Range, c As Range
    Dim Wf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim vR() As Variant
    Dim k As Long, j As Integer
    Dim HosKvikOffIns As Range '<~~Declare a variable

    Set Wf = WorksheetFunction

    Set sht3 = Sheets("Compare")
    Set sht4 = Sheets("Print ready")

    Set ColG = sht3.Range("B3:B88")
    Set ColB = sht3.Range("G3:G86")

    Set HosKvikOffIns = sht4.Range("a1") '<~~ First, set the varialble
For Each c In ColB.Cells
    If Not IsEmpty(c) Then
        With Wf
            n = .CountIfs(ColG, c) 'Error here
            If n = 0 Then
                c.Offset(0, -1).Resize(1, 3).Copy HosKvikOffIns
                Set HosKvikOffIns = HosKvikOffIns.Offset(1, 0)
            End If
        End With
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This just loops straight to End if for me? All the way down, even then ones that are unique values :)

Comment: @ what mean HosKvikOffIns.

Comment: It's the range it should paste in sht4... I'll just edit the code, so you'll see

Comment: Explain what you are going to do with the unique values.

Comment: The entire workbook is actually to match 2 different lists of account overviews... One from the supplier and then what we have in our system. Therefore the invoice and creditmemo numbers should add up. If there is one invoice or creditmemo, which we do not have in our system, then it should copy this along the cell to the right and left of it, and insert it in sht4, which is more manageable to look at :)

Comment: Thanks man, this returns the right value... But there is no way I can get it to paste one by one just below eachother? Just like:             `HosKvikOffIns.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll` and 
            `Set HosKvikOffIns = HosKvikOffIns.Offset(1, 0)`